# Как сделать редирект в Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

Хочу сделать редирект в роде:

```
/user.php?username=pavel
```

Чтобы было так:

```
/user/pavel
```

Что-то такое написал, но для пхп агрументы не передает

```
location /user/ {
    rewrite ^/(\w+)$ /user.php?username=$1;
    rewrite ^/(\w+)+\/$ /user.php?username=$1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /user.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Тут куча примеров - https://pai-bx.com/wiki/nginx/2332-useful-redirects-in-nginx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте этот location:

```
location ^~ /user/ {
    rewrite ^/user/(\w+)/?$ /user.php?username=$1 last;
}
```